# How to gracefully end a process without using CloseMainWindow

Tags: c#, winapi, process

Is there a way to gracefully end a process without using `Process.CloseMainWindow()`?

I have a bunch of processes in a list which I want to end. The process should be ended without `Process.Kill()` to make sure they clean up and end their child processes as well.
I tried *CloseMainWindow*, but unfortunately it will make my process pop up a messagebox with "Do you really want to end the programm?"[Yes][No] which I want to avoid.

The processes have a message handler for `WM_QUERYENDSESSION` but when I tried to send a `WM_QUERYENDSESSION` message to the process, it didn't react on it. It just reacts on `WM_QUIT`, but the behaviour looks like the one when calling `Process.Kill()`.

I couldn't find a proper solution yet. Hopefully I didn't overlooked things in here...

Comment: Are you able to communicate with your processes and tell them to end? That would be the cleanest solution I can think of.

Comment: Based on what information did you conclude, that sending a `WM_QUERYENDSESSION` message were a good idea? It's also unclear, what message pops up, when calling `Process.CloseMainWindow`. Besides, the *"main window"* stored for a process is just a guess. It could well be the wrong window.

Comment: You should look into communication protocols with your applications. By how you describe things you seems to have the source code of both. Look into [Inter Process Communication (IPC)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574(v=vs.85).aspx) and i would suggest the [Named Pipe Thread (NPT)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-use-named-pipes-for-network-interprocess-communication) as i personally find it cleaner and easier to implement. I use NPT and transfer custom c# object to another application and i can read it back on the other side.

Comment: @Sefe I got some pipes for communication to the child processes, but I can't imagine that there is no solution to end it from the mainprocess without killing it entirely or "press the X button".

Comment: With the edit, the solution is a lot simpler: Remove the *"Do you really want to end the program"* prompt. The user just pressed [Alt]+[F4], or clicked the close button. Don't make them answer the same question twice.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well after a while I admit that there seems to be no real answer to this explicit problem.

Since I got control of both parts I just removed the "Do you really want to quit?" pop up like [IInspectable](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1889329/iinspectable) assumed and send a message via the opened pipe to the child process like [Sefe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6859983/sefe) assumed.

Answer (score 1):

Sending the `WM_CLOSE` message is pretty much the same as clicking the close button on a window. Applications will be able to block this request or put up a "Save your changes" confirmation dialog.

Anything beyond this and you risk loosing data. `WM_QUIT` is not something you should be sending.

`WM_QUERYENDSESSION` is a query, you would send that first and then `WM_ENDSESSION` but not all applications will handle these messages.

Win32 does not have a main-window property, it is a .NET concept.

Another thing you should look into is the restart manager feature if you plan on restarting these applications again when you are done with whatever you are doing.

Comment: I want to avoid "clicking the close button" or `WM_CLOSE` because of the pop up window spawn.

Comment: `WM_CLOSE` and the restart manager are the only clean ways to stop applications. Faking a end-session might work or the application might lose its unsaved data or it might ignore the session notification and expect Windows to kill the process.

Comment: @Retnuoc: If you want to prevent a dialog your code pops up from popping up, you're going to have to implement custom logic to do so, and take appropriate steps instead (e.g. auto-saving unsaved changes).

Comment: @Anders Restart manager actually "fakes" `WM_QUERYENDSESSION` and `WM_ENDSESSION` ([Guidelines for Applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373651(v=vs.85).aspx)) but it's propably safer to use as one can specify to only shutdown applications which have opted in for Restart Manager.